# webserver (esp8266) with long loop duration

Tags: webserver, interrupt, arduino-esp8266

I'm currently building a webserver with webpage to control led strips. The website runs fine and I can control a single LED perfectly. When I select a rainbow animation for example (cycle through evry color of the rainbow) this loop takes quit a lot of time (5 seconds per color). When the node mcu (ESP8266) is in that loop inputs from the webserver are not seen. I don't want to write in every animation that I wrote to check for the inputs (these are 50 animations or more) so I came up with an interrupt. I start an timer and everytime (executed in less then 250ms to trigger watchdog) the interrupt is triggered the handlewebserver is executed. When I put my handleClient in the void loop everything works fine, but when I put it in my timerInterrupt the page start constantly reloading. Can anyone tell why? ps: with only controlling a simple led on or off this doenst work eather, thats why I dont incuded the extra code here, you can include a very long delay after turning D4 high to test this :)

```
 
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <Ticker.h>
 
Ticker blinker;
 
const char ssid[] = "*****";
const char pass[] = "*****";
 
// Web server port
const uint16_t port = 80;
boolean ledStatus = false;
 
// Web server object declaration
ESP8266WebServer server(port);

 /*
String webPage =
    "<html>\r\n" \
    "<head>\r\n" \
    "<title>ESP8266 Basic Page LED</title>\r\n" \
    "</head>\r\n" \
    "<body>\r\n" \
    "<h1>LED</h1>\r\n" \
    "<form method=\"post\">\r\n" \
    "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"led\" value=\"ON\">\r\n" \
    "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"led\" value=\"OFF\">\r\n" \
    "</form>\r\n" \
    "</body>\r\n" \
    "</html>\r\n";
  */

  const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
     <title>ESP8266 Basic Page LED</title>
  </HEAD>
  <style>
.panel{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color rgba(255,208,142,1);
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #89cff0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color-picker {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css"/> <!-- 'classic' theme -->
<BODY>
 
  <div class="color-picker"></div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel"></div>

  <h1>LED</h1>
  <form method="post" id="formie">
    <input type="submit" name="led" value="ON">
    <input type="submit" name="led" value="OFF">

     leds dimmen:
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" name="slider" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p class="valueSlider">Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>

   <input type="text" id="field" name="fname" value="John"><br><br>

   

  
  </form>

  
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@simonwep/pickr/dist/pickr.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  let panel = document.getElementById('panel');

    // Simple example, see optional options for more configuration.
const pickr = Pickr.create({
    el: '.color-picker',
    theme: 'classic', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'

    swatches: [
        'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
        'rgba(233, 30, 99, 1)',
        'rgba(156, 39, 176, 1)',
        'rgba(103, 58, 183, 1)',
        'rgba(63, 81, 181, 1)',
        'rgba(33, 150, 243, 1)',
        'rgba(3, 169, 244, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 188, 212, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 150, 136, 1)',
        'rgba(76, 175, 80, 1)',
        'rgba(139, 195, 74, 1)',
        'rgba(205, 220, 57, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 235, 59, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
    ],

    components: {

        // Main components
        preview: true,
        opacity: false,
        hue: true,

        // Input / output Options
        interaction: {
            hex: false,
            rgba: false,
            hsla: false,
            hsva: false,
            cmyk: false,
            input: false,
            clear: false,
            save: false
        }
    }
});

pickr.on('change', (color, instance) => {
    //console.log('change', color, instance);

    var testieee = color.toRGBA(); // Returns [r, g, b, a]
    console.log(testieee);
    this.panel.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(${color[0]},${color[1]},${color[2]},${color[3]})';

   
    var myForm = document.getElementById('formie');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    
    hiddenInput.type = 'hidden';
    hiddenInput.name = 'myarray';
    
    hiddenInput.value = JSON.stringify(testieee);


     var testelement = document.getElementById('field');
    testelement.value = JSON.stringify(testieee);

})
  
  
  </script>
</BODY>





</HTML>
)=====";


void handleRoot()
{
 

    String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
 
}
 
void handleLed()
{
    // *** Turn on or off the LED ***
    if (server.arg("led") == "ON")
        digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
    else if (server.arg("led") == "OFF")
        digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);

   
   if (server.arg("slider").toInt() > 50)
        digitalWrite(D2, HIGH);
    else
        digitalWrite(D2, LOW);

    

    
 
    server.sendHeader("Location","/");
    server.send(303);
}

//=======================================================================
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR onTimerISR(){
    //digitalWrite(LED,!(digitalRead(LED)));  //Toggle LED Pin
    server.handleClient(); /* when It moves to here the server is constantly reloading and starst again a few times! */
    timer1_write(250000);
    Serial.printf("execute interrupt");
}
 
void setup()
{
    // Set pin as output
    pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
    // Setup serial communication
    Serial.begin(74880);
 
    // *** Connect to a WiFi acces point ***
    Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.printf(" Connected\n");
    Serial.printf("IP address: %s\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
 
    // *** Start web server ***
    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);
    server.on("/", HTTP_POST, handleLed);
    server.begin();
    Serial.printf("Web server started at port %d\n", port);

    //Initialize Ticker every 0.5s / 2 and a little bit less --> so under 250ms
    timer1_attachInterrupt(onTimerISR);
    timer1_enable(TIM_DIV16, TIM_EDGE, TIM_SINGLE);
    timer1_write(250000); //120000 us

    
}


 
void loop()
{
    //server.handleClient(); /* when It stays here everything is fine! */
    //server.handleClient();
    //Serial.print(server.arg("fname"));
}
```

Comment: you should let the loop() loop. so code the animation in a function which  does what is needed for the current state of the animation and then returns

Comment: As I said in my question this animation takes to long, therefore inputs from the webpage are not seen fast enouf. If an animation takes to long the watchdog is triggered also (250ms) and webpage can go offline because the function isn't recalled for to long. So there's defenitly need for an interrupt to recal that function, my question is why doent work it? because the loop does it run periodic and so does the interrupt

Comment: does the animation function have delay() cals?

Comment: yess it has, however a function with just a led doenst have delay function and it doens't work either therefore. Normally the timer would interupt that code no matter where it is, execute it and go on where it was. An example of an animation if you need it `void colorWipe(byte red, byte green, byte blue, int SpeedDelay) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      setPixel(i, red, green, blue);
      showStrip();
      delay(SpeedDelay);
  }
}`

Comment: rewrite it to millis timing. you can't handle web in interrupt

Comment: I will try that, may I ask why that doenst work?